# Linux configuration required to run ros extensively

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish to install Ubuntu on my 256GB Mac, I wanted to know a rough estimate of storage and RAM that I should provide to the Ubuntu OS on my laptotp to run ROS smoothly. As far as my usage of ROS is concerned, I will be using ROS extensively so please suggest according to that.

Also, please suggest me a Linux OS best suited for most operations.

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274643/linux-configuration-required-to-run-ros-extensively/) by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-10-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on 2017-10-31**:
Are you going to be using a virtual machine or real install? A real install is recommended because Rviz and Gazebo will give you lots of headaches with a virtual machine.

**Comment by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on 2017-10-31**:
A real install, not virtual machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are dual booting, then the Ubuntu partition will use all your ram so no worries there. Talking about storage, I think it depends on your application, 80GB seems decent, even 50GB or 30GB would do if you plan on only learning ROS.
If you want to deal with pointclouds, simulations, ROS industrial or something different then it'll eat up your disk really fast. So 100GB on that case.

Also, I've seen great success using Parallels.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on 2017-11-01**:
parallels is a virtual machine, right?

But wouldnt the number of downloads in ROS, make it difficult to work with a virtual machine?

Isnt dual boot better?

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-01**:
Dual boot is definitely better, way better, I had some students use VMs and when you are trying to load gazebo + rviz it lags a lot, almost impossible to work with. If you go the VM route, the best one is VMWare. They have a free tier. For parallels, you have to pay so there is that.

**Comment by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on 2017-11-01**:
So dual boot 100GB then, thanks :)